# How to save nested replies on a comment in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am inserting a comment like this:

```
const commentObj = {
    postId: new ObjectId(postId),
    userId: user._id,
    text: comment,
    replies: []
};
await db.collection('comments').insertOne(commentObj, {});
```

Now inserting a reply to the comment:

```
const replyObj = {
    parent: new ObjectId(commentId),
    userId: user._id,
    text: comment,
}

await db.collection('comments').findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: new ObjectId(commentId) },
    { $push: { replies: replyObj } }
);
```

Now how do I handle a new reply to reply above created? So it would be nested replies like

```
some post
>commentA
  >replyA-a
    >replyA-a-a
      >replyA-a-a-a
        >replyA-a-a-a-a
  >replyA-b
>commentB
>commentC
```

**Update:** I have tried using ancestors like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G7NSlsuZNLY) but not sure how do I query it in a way that UI can render it

Comment: Are you expecting the format in UI/display level? It is suggested to avoid recursive schema with dynamic level of recursion in MongoDB, as it would cause unnecessary complexity and performance issue to queries.

Comment: @ray Updated question with link

Comment: The schema makes sense to me. It looks to me that it requires non-trivial processing at js/frontend level. I would leave it to other experts in that area to help.